# How to loop through a string and check if it matches current character of the same string in C?

Tags: c, cs50

I am a noob so please forgive me for being dumb...

Basically, say the key is 26 characters, composed of the letters of the alphabet with no repeating chars allowed.

So what I want to do is take the first letter of the key, hold on to it, then search through the rest of the key to see if any letters are repeated. If so, it should return an error value of 1.

```
string keycopy = "JTREKYAVOGDXPSNCUIZLFBMWHQ";

for (int i = 0; i < keylength; i++)
    {
        // check if all is alphabet, check for repeated chars

        int c = keycopy[i]; //current char, save and then loop
        
        if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Alphabet only please\n");
                return 1;
            }
        for (int j = i + 1; j < keylength; j++)
        {
            if (keycopy[j] == c)
            {
                printf("No repeating characters please\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm pretty sure here that I am taking the first char of keycopy and comparing it to the 2nd char of keycopy only, but I want to compare the first char of keycopy and compare it to the entire rest of keycopy, one char at a time. I haven't learned about pointers yet.

Comment: Your code has a compile-time error since you have an unreachable statement. 
Compile and run your code before post it in a forum.

Remove the return statement you throw if the char is not an Alphabet.

Make it something like if(! (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) return -1;

Comment: Note the check for letters can be done more succinctly with [isalpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_character_classification#isalpha).

Comment: @Schwern, there are lots of things to improve, for instance why only limit the task to 7-bit Ascii, there is the entire unicode space to handle, but for a beginner task the important is to write something run it and understand it. If the code is optimal or not is a later concern.

Comment: Oh thanks everyone, it now works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second for loop is dead code, it is never reached as the `continue` will skip to the next iteration of the for loop.

replace with a

```
    if (!((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')))
    {
        printf("Alphabet only please\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

I would also consider it good practice to declare `c` as a `char` instead of an `int`, it will reduce the risks of unforeseen errors later.

```
char c = keycopy[i]; //current char, save and then loop
```

*There is a more efficient way of testing if a character have been seen before without the second loop, but for this exercise I think your current code is good enough for now*

Comment: "Declare c as a char instead of an int" is a curious idea.  What functional difference do you see?

Comment: The more efficient method would be to keep an array counting which characters you've seen. There's only 52 possibilities: `int seen[52]`. 'a' would be seen[0], 'z' would be seen[25], 'A' would be seen[26], and 'Z' would be seen[51]: `int key = islower(c) ? c - 'a' : c - 'A' + 26; seen[key] += 1;` Or, since it's such a trivial amount of memory, the much simpler: `int seen[256]; seen[c] += 1;`

Comment: Hygiene only. The size of each element in the string is a char and it is compared to a char, it is good practice to not convert the size

Comment: @Schwern Note: With `int seen[256]; seen[c] += 1;`, UB when `c < 0`.

Comment: Yes `int seen[numchars]` is more efficient, but I decided not to add this level of complexity to this answer right now as it would shadow the first issue

Comment: Simson you are a total bro!! Also thanks for keeping it simple for a noob!